# saltstack master minion configuration in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, salt-stack

I have installed salt master and minion in different instance and I have followed these steps and installation process

[image]

and i have got an error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory
Your private key: `/etc/private.pem` has wrong (0755) permissions

Whereas it should be 600.
To fix:
`chmod 600 /etc/private.pem` (assuming proper owner of `/etc/private.pem`)

Comment: what about permission denied(publickey)

Comment: I guess this is what you are experiencing now? I have assumed that your `/etc/private.pem` is owned by the same user that starts whatever the process is that you use (salt-master?).  By issuing `chmod 600 /etc/private.pem` you've stated that only the owner can read this file. Now you must ensure that this owner is the same user that start your process.

Comment: yes i am running with same users but the same problem is arrising.I need a clarification on what configurations that to be done on salt-minion